# Python on arduino, inputs waitng for pocess tofinish

Tags: python, arduino, multiprocessing

I have simple set with 3 buttons and a led. I want to regulate blink of the led by buttons, every button have assigned "duration" of blinking. My program waits till the blinking part is done until it reads inputs. I tried multiprocessing but I couldn't make it work.

I also implemented light power regulation but it works fine.

Here it is "working" code:

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM3')

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

analA = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
wejA = board.get_pin('d:2:i')
wejB = board.get_pin('d:4:i')
wejC = board.get_pin('d:7:i')
led = board.get_pin('d:10:p')

x = False
y = False
z = False

f = 1

while True:
    x = wejA.read()
    y = wejB.read()
    z = wejC.read()
    analog = analA.read()

    if x == True:
        f = 3
        print(analog, x, y, z, f)

    if y == True:
        f = 1
        print(analog, x, y, z, f)

    if z == 1:
        f = 0.3
        print(analog, x, y, z, f)


    led.write(analog)
    time.sleep(f)
    led.write(0)
    time.sleep(f)
```

I blindly tried multiprocessing but I failed, there is my attempt:

```
import pyfirmata
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM3')

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

analA = board.get_pin('a:0:i')
wejA = board.get_pin('d:2:i')
wejB = board.get_pin('d:4:i')
wejC = board.get_pin('d:7:i')
led = board.get_pin('d:10:p')

x = False
y = False
z = False

f = 1


def wejscia():
        x = wejA.read()
        y = wejB.read()
        z = wejC.read()
        analog = analA.read()

        if x == True:
            f = 3
            print(analog, x, y, z, f)

        if y == True:
            f = 1
            print(analog, x, y, z, f)

        if z == 1:
            f = 0.3
            print(analog, x, y, z, f)


def wyjscia():
        analog = analA.read()

        led.write(analog)
        time.sleep(f)
        led.write(0)
        time.sleep(f)


while True:
    p1 = Process(target=wejscia)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=wyjscia)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

How to make program check the inputs and do the outputs at the same time?

I've just started programing so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue some time ago.
Adding this helped me fix it.

```
pin.enable_reporting()
```

This essentially listens  to an input pin and reports its values.
So i think adding this when you are initializing the pins will solve the issue.

```
wejA.enable_reporting()
wejB.enable_reporting()
wejC.enable_reporting()
```